# Wandb: How to show grouped average in the advanced legend section

Tags: machine-learning, wandb

I was working on logging my seeded ML trainings in waits and biases and i can see nice visualization of what i did.

In the advanced Legend section I can see.

```
[[ ${mean} σ ${stddev} (${min}, ${max}) ]] ${run:displayName}
```

where the `[[ ${mean} σ ${stddev} (${min}, ${max}) ]]` part is visible when I do hover.

How can I append this values to the text shown like below

```
[[ ${mean} σ ${stddev} (${min}, ${max}) ]] ${run:displayName}  - ${mean} σ ${stddev}
```

Thanks for the help